# Hibernate validation with strong typing in Jersey with Jackson

Tags: java, hibernate, validation, jersey, jackson

I am implementing a REST API using Jersey. I want to validate all of the inputs to my service (query params, path params, DTOs) and am looking into some options - one that looks like it does the job is [Jersey Bean Validation](https://jersey.java.net/documentation/latest/bean-validation.html). I also want to have everything in the service strongly typed - for example, instead of using `String` to represent all of the bits of data, where you'd have a function like this:

```
public Order getOrder(String customerId);
```

Instead define types for each bit of data (the benefit of this is to let the compiler catch incorrect data being passed to functions, being able to obfuscate the underlying value in the `toString` method for logging, knowing that the value is definitely valid if you have an instance and so on), so you end up with functions like this:

```
public Order getOrder(CustomerId customerId);
```

And types like this:

```
public class CustomerId {

    private final String value;

    public CustomerId(String value) {
        this.value = validate(value);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private String validate(String value) {
        // Do some validation here
    }
}
```

The Jersey Bean Validation examples do not use strong types like above. For example:

```
@Path("/")
class MyResourceClass {

    @POST
    @Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
    public void registerUser(
        @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z -]{1,50}") @FormParam("name") String name) {
        ...
    }
}
```

The build in validation is nice in that you get some features for free:

- 400 bad request exception returned on any validation error
- Optionally include the validation error in the response
- None of the code in your function gets executed if validation fails

However, there are a few problems:

- You have to remember to include the annotations everywhere the data
  can be input to your system, so it's hard to apply consistently
- You may end up with different definitions of what is valid for a type
- You don't get the strong typing benefits mentioned above

Does anyone know of a way to get all of these benefits. I tried defining a type like this:

```
public class CustomerId {

    private final String value;

    public CustomerId(String value) {
        this.value = validate(value);
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }

    private String validate(String value) {
        if (!Pattern.matches("[a-zA-Z -]{1,50}", value)) {
            throw new ConstraintViolationException(new HashSet<ConstraintViolation<?>>());
        }
        return value;
    }
}
```

But it seems the exception  doesn't get handled the same way by Jersey, and the response code you get if the validation fails is 404 instead of 400.

Does anyone know of a way to get the best of both worlds?

Answer (score 1):

This is from the spec, in regards to how errors are handle when constructing `@XxxParam`s

> ... if the [..] is annotated with `@MatrixParam`, `@QueryParam` or `@PathParam` then an implementation MUST generate an instance of `NotFoundException` (404 status) that wraps the thrown exception and no entity; if the field or property is annotated with `@HeaderParam` or `@CookieParam` then an implementation MUST generate an instance of
> `BadRequestException` (400 status) that wraps the thrown exception and no entity.

Though not listed here, `@FormParam` falls under the 400 bracket.

> "Does anyone know of a way to get the best of both worlds?"

We can override this behavior by throwing a `WebApplicationException`. We could then create an `ExceptionMapper` for the exception, and then just delegate to the `ExceptionMapper` that normally handles `ConstraintViolationException`. I couldn't find any *clear* detail on this behavior. I mean you would expect that the `ExceptionMapper` should get called anyway, but it doesn't if it is isn't an instance of `WebApplicationException`. So you can make your exception extend `WebApplicationException`.

```
public static class MyException extends WebApplicationException {
    
    private final ConstraintViolationException cve;
    
    public MyException(ConstraintViolationException cve) {
        this.cve = cve;
    }
    
    public ConstraintViolationException getConstraintViolationException() {
        return cve;
    }
}
```

Then create an `ExceptionMapper` for it. In the mapper, we simply delegate to the [original mapper that handles `ConstraintViolationException`](https://github.com/jersey/jersey/blob/master/ext/bean-validation/src/main/java/org/glassfish/jersey/server/validation/internal/ValidationExceptionMapper.java#L74)

```
public static class MyExceptionMapper implements ExceptionMapper<MyException> {
    
    @Context
    private Providers providers;

    @Override
    public Response toResponse(MyException exception) {
        ExceptionMapper<ValidationException> mapper 
                = providers.getExceptionMapper(ValidationException.class);
        return mapper.toResponse(exception.getConstraintViolationException());
    }
}
```

Then you can just throw `MyException`. If you don't care for an error response body, and all you want is a 400 status, you can forget everything above and simply throw a `BadRequestException`. Or if you don't care for the response entity that the `ConstraintViolationException` mapper sends out, you can create your own response in the `MyExceptionMapper`, or create a `Response` inside the `CustomerId` class and pass it the `BadRequestException` constructor. So you have some options.

A headache from this approach I could see is that you need to create your own `ConstraintViolation`. That can get old really quick.

The other approach I could see is to use `@BeanParam` and `@Valid`

```
public static class CustomerId {

    @FormParam("cust")
    @Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z -]{1,50}")
    private  String value;

    public void setValue(String value) {
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return value;
    }
}

@POST
@Path("form")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public String postForm(@BeanParam @Valid CustomerId custId) {
```

The problem with this approach is that your bean is now stuck with `@FormParam` and is not reusable with other `@XxxParam`s.

So you have some trade-offs. Hope this gives you some good information to work with.

---

#### UPDATE

Oh and the last option I can think of, is similar to second one above, but you aren't tied to the `@XxxParam` in the bean

```
public static class CustomerId {

    //@FormParam("cust")
    @javax.validation.constraints.Pattern(regexp="[a-zA-Z -]{1,50}")
    private  String value;

    public CustomerId(String value) {
        //this.value = validate(value);
        this.value = value;
    }
    ...
}

@POST
@Path("form")
@Consumes("application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
public String postForm(@FormParam("cust") @Valid CustomerId custId) {
```

Think the last option might be the way to go, but you still need to remember to always annotate with `@Valid`, which sounds like something you were trying to avoid.